# Attach fragment onTabSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an `Activity` that is used as container, with some tabs attached to the `ActionBar`.
If I swipe left or right the correct tab is loaded, but I was trying to add the same behaviour if I click the tab name.

Assuming the variable `myFragment` is of type `MyFragmentClass`.

The code below gives me a strange error: `attach(android.app.fragment) can't be applied to MyFragmentClass`.

[image: Error before runtime]

```
tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                //SOME CONTROL BEFORE ATTACHING

                    ft.attach(myFragment);

                //SOME CONTROL AFTER ATTACHING
            }
....
```

`MyFragmentClass` is defined to extend `Fragment` (taken from `support.v4`, or else it give me some problems).

How can I attach it without problems?

Comment: i haven't run the code... the problem is before runtime, as the line is underlined in red

Comment: Eclipse? Which error is giving you?

Comment: show me the underline line.

Comment: the line is `ft.attach(myFragment)`

Comment: check your import statements and replace this lines 

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.app.FragmentActivity;

**Replace with this**

    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: I already have imports from support.v4

Comment: I have no time right now to review your code.
but this link will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897298/android-actionbar-tablistener-and-support-v4-fragment

Comment: Is your myFragment 's imports coming from support library?

Comment: Yep! It imports from `support.v4`